# Is it possible to make geolocation validation?

Tags: validation, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

To make more clear what inspired this question, I'm making a mobile app where people rate in real time how nightclubs are doing and would be very good if there existed an way to make sure the person is actually there to rate if it's bad or good.

PS. I thought about comparing the coordinates of the location of the person versus the place's coordinates. Don't know if it's technically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you read the location from GPS. make sure you get the location only from GPS not from other locations service like cell tower or wifi.
A GPS location in most cases is acurate within 3- 30m.

Then just calculate the distance from user coordinates (latitue, longitude) to nightclubs (latiidude, longitude)
if the distance is <50m then the person is standing very near to th enntry of the club.

But dont forget inside the club you will not recieve GPS. GPS needs free view to sky.

Comment: Thanks very much @AlexWien, very good explanation! Do you recomend to make a database column for the coordinates and compare values or make an 'instant' data comparison?

Comment: I would just store the coordinates in a text file: 5 digits after comma is sufficeint (accuracy then is 1.11m): clubname,latitude, longitude. Then read them all in main memory. I personally would store it in a binary file, but this may or may not to much work for you. In java this is simple, on my iphone with ios it was many work to write and read a custom binary file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. If the app requests the GPS support and the location co-ordinates at real time. It would actually verify if the person is at there.